# Gradle builds really slow with a multi-project structure

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dex

When building with gradle on a multi-project setup containing roughly 140 projects/libraries, the build time took 1 hour and 22 minutes. And i was using `--parallel`. And our ANT build takes less than 20 minutes without parallel building.

Here is exactly what i did.

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build --parallel
```

I did a little testing it seems like the dexing is taking the longest amount of time. Is there a way to get the gradle process to re-use the stuff it has already dexed? If the libraries have already been built, it should re-use the already dexed libraries.

I saw the option `--no-rebuild`, but when i run with that option it says the following

```
File '/path/to/project/build/libs/project.aar' specified for property 'bundle' does not exist.
```

I replaced the file path and project name with generic stuff.

Using Gradle 1.9-rc-3

---

Additional information(15 Jan 2014):

`preDexDebug` and `preDexRelease` took a VERY long time on each project. Much longer than any other task.

---

Progress(15 Jan 2014):

Ok, for now, i put `preDexLibraries = false` into all of the `build.gradle` files. However, i still would like to know a centralize place that i can put that entry and it affect all the other `build.gradle` files.

However, now `dexRelease` and `dexDebug` are taking a long time. Is there any way that i can tell the build to only do the `dexDebug` or `dexRelease` and skip the other one?

---

Progress(15 Jan 2014):

Using `assembleDebug` worked. However, it still seems like it is not re-using the already dexed libraries. Because dexing is still taking forever. It takes about a minute for each project. **Is there a way to get gradle to re-use the already dexed libraries? Or is there a different reason why the build is still taking about an hour?** Our ANT process takes less than 15 minutes.

Comment: How's the progress now? Still taking 58min? It would be interesting to get an update on how much the gradle developers have improved it since January (2014).

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Improving-Build-Server-performance.

Comment: where should I put assembleDebug, is it under android{ dexOptions{ }} ?

Answer (score 20):

Doing a `clean` you actually delete the already predexed libraries.
As suggested [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=it&fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/o2gjl3U4bSA) you could save some time on `clean` builds by disabling predexing (because at the next build they will be deleted):

```groovy
android {
  dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do i put that setting? I am not going to be able to put that into all of the `build.gradle` files. That would be ridiculous. Is there another place i can put that, where it will affect all the builds?

Comment: Ok, for now, i put that entry into all of the `build.gradle` files. However, i still would like to know a centralize place that i can put that entry and it affect all the other `build.gradle`. However, now `dexRelease` and `dexDebug` are taking a long time. Is there any way that i can tell the build to only do the `dexDebug` or `dexRelease` and skip the other one?

Comment: Just use `assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease` tasks instead of `build`.

Comment: Ok by adding the `preDexLibraries=false` and running `assembleDebug` it reduced the build time from 3+ hours to 58 minutes. That is still MUCH longer than our ANT build. The `dexDebug` is still taking almost a minute for each project. Is there anyway to reduce this time? Our ant build is re-using already built libraries and the gradle process does not appear to be re-using. +1 for your help so far.

Answer (score 6):

[According to this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/iius619cxmU).

> Right now each project will pre-dex its dependencies on its own. This
>   means 2 components depending on the same library will both run pre-dex
>   on that library's classes.jar which is silly. We're looking at fixing
>   this.

Comment: There's now an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66807) filed for this.

Answer (score 2):

**Did you try setting the parameters of the Gradles compiler?**

If you have remote dependencies, each time you run the project it will be operated with remote resources using the network. You should define the instruction to the Gradles compiler to that him to work offline using:

```
--offline
```

Here I leave you a screenshot of the compiler settings for better performance:

[image]

Or what is the same...

[image]

**Source: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html**