# Extremely slow gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-build, gradlew

The following measures were taken to speed up gradle build from this ([SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324849/android-studio-gradle-build-speed-up))

1. org.gradle.parallel=true, org.gradle.daemon=true
2. build from terminal and not from android Studio
3. building with ./gradlew assembleDebug --offline

Problem:

1. Even after these measures build times can take upto 6-8 minutes for a single line of code change! and during this time computer mostly freezes and nothing else can be done except to stare at the terminal. I've noticed that "app:dexDebug" takes a lot of time in this. What are the possible causes?

Relevant files:

1. [Terminal build dump](https://gist.github.com/firehawk895/9abf602936f1421c7399)
2. [build.gradle(app)](https://gist.github.com/firehawk895/17706730452d85bb6ae0)
3. [build.gradle(project)](https://gist.github.com/firehawk895/b1c9ed3a292dfff301a1)

System details:

1. Android Studio 1.2.2
2. Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Have you tried disabling lint checks?

Comment: May be system dependent,In my studio it only takes 20 - 30 sec average.For single line of code in max 10 sec

Comment: @user2217535 my peer works in windows on the same project on a slower computer, but in windows. and it is 3x times faster for him.

Comment: @PedroOliveira I'm building from terminal. is lint check done then? if so I don't know how to disable it.

Comment: The dexDebug could take a lot of time if you're using proguard. If so disable proguard for debug builds.

Comment: @kha anything specific that I should add in my case?

Comment: @Ankan-Zerob you're running from the console so I'm not sure what the command line changes are. Try running the build in AndroidStudio with those options in the answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try disabling your lint checks by adding this code to your build.gradle

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.toLowerCase().contains("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Also you can use the `--profile` parameter to export a html report of what's taking so long in your build time

**EDIT**: removed the debug check

Comment: trying that right now. I'm adding this to the project build.gradle and running with --profile.

Comment: Good luck. Also add the report to the original post so other people can help you :)

Comment: thanks for the profile tip! some ugly task execution times have come up: app:preDexDebug 3m6.93s 
:app:dexDebug 44.510s 
:app:compileDebugJava 28.332s 
:app:packageDebug 22.577s

Comment: Are you making a clean build? If so you can use `preDexLibraries = false`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136780/3410697. What about proguard/minify? Is it enabled?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem: our build took about 4 minutes. After some research, we get next steps:

Try turning on offline work in your Gradle settings (Ctrl + Alt + S for the Settings, then Build Tools -> Gradle settings). Usually, we do not update libraries so often and Gradle will not check that they are up to date.

Multidex increases the time for build: [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html). To mitigate this, you can add additional flavors for debug and production builds, setting for debug builds minSdk = 21 (suggestion from official site).

If you have several modules in project, try to flatten them into one or at least extract "Library project" and connect it as .aar

As a result, our build time decreased to about minute - minute and a half. Hope these suggestions will help you too.

And if we will talk about small changes, starting from Android Studio 2.0, it is possible to use Instant run and Incremental build, which makes small changes in method or layout even faster.

Answer (score -5):

Understand that Gradle Build has nothing to do with your CPU Speed or RAM. The reason why the Build gets slower in your PC is due to your Internet Connection. The build can take nearly ~100 MB approx. of data to complete it's process. Even if your Internet Connection is fast and your connection's PING speed is slow, it takes more time.

Comment: with the offline parameter, internet is no longer required.