# Gradle build finished in 9 minute in hello world application in android studio

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I have 4 GB RAM and Intel i3 4005U CPU . and the build time is Extremely slow.

I tried the suggestions in this post [Extremely slow gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204456/extremely-slow-gradle-build)
and the time reduced only to 6 minute and I still find it Extremely slow.

is the problem is in my system specifications?

if so , I want to know what is the system requirements to decrease the build time for a hello world app to about 10~20 second.

Comment: you are currently on the minimum hardware requirements for android studio , i am on 8gb ram and i7 7700 cpu  and the build would take 20-30 seconds so i would be surprised if you could reach that result on your hardware

Comment: @BilalRammal  Your comment confirms for me that Android Studio is completely screwed.  30 seconds for "hello world" is **BEYOND pathetic**.  I have an *entire native code game engine* with three subprojects, over 120 C++ files, some of them well over a thousand lines long, and Visual Studio compiles *the whole thing from scratch* in 1 minute 34 seconds, on old hardware, over network shares.