# Android multi-module Gradle build slow even without any changes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project with multiple modules where the build time is slow even if I try to rebuild it without changing anything.

Its structure is similar to:

[image: Simplified project setup]

There are more "parent" (and independent parent siblings) and "feature" modules but the setup is that of the picture.

My `gradle.properties`file is as follows:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -Xms2048m
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

And I'm using the Gradle version 3.5 and the plugin version 2.4.0-alpha7.

The project also uses multidex (`javaMaxHeapSize "4g"` and `jumboMode true`), data binding, kotlin alongside java, and several annotation processors.

When a build, I can see multiple threads running different tasks in parallel for most of the project, except mostly for the final "app" module (which I assume is normal).

But a lot of time seems to be spent on different 
::compileJavaWithJavac tasks. Even without changing anything, build takes about 30 secs on a MacBook Pro i7 with 16 Gb RAM.

If I change one line of code inside a method of a feature module (without even changing the method's signature), the build time goes over 1:30 minutes.

Are these normal times? Is there something I can optimise further to improve build times?

I also checked some of the other answers:

- From [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125302/gradle-builds-really-slow-with-a-multi-project-structure), setting `preDexLibraries = false` doesn't help and I already use `assembleDebug`
- `incremental = true` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006075/extremely-long-build-with-gradle-android-studio) doesn't work and is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522668/android-dexoptions-incremental-property-is-deprecated)
- Disabling instant run seems to help a little but not much
- The project's build flavour discussed above already sets `minSdkVersion 21`

Comment: Do you finally found the culprit for long build times? I've encountered similar problem.

Comment: This is really eating the productive time google should release clear documentation the approach when there are multiple module in Android application  & how to increase the speed

Answer (score 0):

you should make the feature module independent as much you can and any dependency with other module please consider the stub. A kind of the proxy which contain only interface feature1 -> featureonestub->feature2

Comment: What do you mean by "any dependency with other module please consider the stub"?

Comment: use interface module resolve the compile time dependency and use dagger or any DI frameworks to provide runtime implementation